# Avoiding code duplication in step definitions

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumberjs

I have following navigation path for an airlines site:

Page1--->Page2(booking engine/booking happens here)----->page3(giving booking number)----->page4(opening booking details)

Page4 have two pop up links upon clicking on which each it opens two popups.
I have to check both pop up details by opening them one by one.

Gherkin:

```
         Scenario:...
Line1    Given I have a url
Line2    When I open the page1
Line3    And I go to page 2 
Line4    And do the booking
Line5    And I go to page 3
Line6    And I enter booking number
Line7    And I click enter
Line8    Then it should open page4
Line9    When I click popup1 link1
Line10   Then It should open popup1
Line11   And Details of popup1 should be proper
Line12   When I click on popup2 link
Line13   Then It should open popup2
Line14   And details of popup2 should be proper
```

Above Gherkin has a problem of `multiple When-Then pairs` in single scenario which is not recommended. From line1 to line8 is common code between opening two popups. I can write above as:

```
         Background:
Line1    Given I have a url
Line2    When I open the page1
Line3    And I go to page 2 
Line4    And do the booking
Line5    And I go to page 3
Line6    And I enter booking number
Line7    And I click enter

         Scenario: First Popup
Line8    When I click popup1 link1
Line10   Then It should open popup1
Line11   And Details of popup1 should be proper

         Scenario: Second Popup
Line12   When I click popup1 link1
Line13   Then It should open popup1
Line14   And Details of popup1 should be proper
```

Now Line 1 to line7 is common but now problem is it will duplicate the code and execution both from line 1 to7 in both scenario's step definitions.

So I want to ask what should be the right approach to handle these kind of scenarios so that scenarios in gherkin test individual behavior and there is no code duplication in step definition also?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, make interdependent scenarios is a bad idea and will not be supported on cucumber-jvm, so a "depends on" kind of solution will not be the answer here.

The solution require to use the same driver to preserve the state of the page and pass this driver across the tests, usually in company of a driver manager class to fetch and store the driver/operate with it:

You can use a Hook Definition class with @BeforeAll notation in the Hook definition classes in order to execute common code and helper methods before the tests, something like this (java example):

```
public class CucumberHooks {

    @BeforeAll
    public static void cucumberBeforeAll() {
        //General code to all test, probably instantiate the driver from driver manager
    }

    @Before
    public void cucumberBefore(Scenario scenario) {
        //Operation before each test, setting the driver to the needed state.
    }

    @After
    public void cucumberAfterTest() {
        //Closing resources or something.
    }
}
```

Also you could implement PicoContainer to share data with dependency injection, this gives you the possibility to share information and behaviors between Step definition classes.